# Nginx upstream timed out

Tags: php, nginx

So I have recently installed nginx and now It is giving me some kind of error and closing nginx every like.. 2 hours? How can I fix it? I am getting the same error just before it closes in  the error log I also get a lot of other error in my error log if that is anything to do with it?

I used nginx on a windows 2008 server with PHP...

```
    2015/04/06 14:07:29 [error] 5812#5480: *552 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 108.162.229.140, server: http://mywebsite.com, request: "GET /assets/ajax/get_bar.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "http://mywebsite.com/play"
2015/04/06 14:07:31 [error] 5812#5480: *600 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 141.101.98.47, server: centralrp.co.uk, request: "GET /assets/ajax/get_bar.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "centralrp.co.uk", referrer: "http://centralrp.co.uk/play"
2015/04/06 14:10:19 [error] 5812#5480: *663 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 141.101.98.47, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /home HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "http://mywebsite.com/index"
2015/04/06 14:19:52 [error] 5812#5480: *665 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 141.101.98.100, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mywebsite.com"
2015/04/06 14:21:29 [error] 5812#5480: *667 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 141.101.98.100, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "http://mywebsite.com/"
```

That above is the error log and I ge tthem errors every time before it closes, and here is my config..

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
root /Dropbox/Website;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            rewrite ^/hk/(.*)$ /index.php?hk=$1;
    rewrite ^/(|/)$ /index.php?url=$1;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ /index.php?url=$1;
    rewrite ^/(.*).htm$ /$1.php;
    rewrite ^/business/manage/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?bm=$2&cid=$1;
    rewrite ^/tickets/manage/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?url=manage_ticket&t=$1 last;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ .php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/Dropbox/Website/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to location

```
proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
```

Example,

```
location /cron/ {

...    

proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
```

}

Comment: Still the same, it just closed much sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using fastcgi you may actually need to set fastcgi_read_timeout.

Here's the link : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout

```
location ~ .php$ {
  fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with the diagnoses of such problems, but there are some clues you might check on your system. "upstream timeout" might be caused by too many client requests, or that somewhere in the request handling php code is blocked, due to network/dns/database/etc failure and the default timeout is too long, thus fastcgi is blocked and not able to handle subsequent requests. Maybe you could check fastcgi or your php code alone first without nginx to validate that it's functioning well.